# Making a button change opacity on button press UIKit

Tags: swift, uikit

OK I feel really weird for asking this question.. I started coding in Swift after SwiftUI and just never had to know this.. but..

How do I get the *default* behavior of a button.. where when I press it, the opacity changes (in UIKit). I thought it would be default behavior but obviously its not..

Here is what I have so far in my button configuration

```
private func configure() {   
   layer.cornerRadius = 10
   setTitleColor(.white, for: .normal)
   titleLabel?.font = UIFont.preferredFont(forTextStyle: .headline)
   translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false

   layer.borderWidth = 2
   layer.borderColor = UIColor.systemPink.cgColor
}
```

Comment: There are [touch events](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/touches_presses_and_gestures/handling_touches_in_your_view?language=objc) you can listen to

Comment: You can also make your own subclass of UIButton: use `addTarget` to implement `[.touchDown, .touchDragEnter]` for the "down" action, and `[.touchUpInside, .touchCancel, .touchDragExit]` for the "up" action

Answer (score 4):

The behavior you are describing is that of a `.system` UIButton as opposed to a `.custom` UIButton. If you create your button to be of type `.system` you get the proposed behavior for free. If the button is created by saying `UIButton()`, it is *not* a `.system` button.

Comment: Btw I think setting type only works in the initializer, so for the system button, it's `UIButton(type: .system)`

Comment: also creating button in Storyboard provides desired  .system button behaviour